# JavaScript issues in Firefox 9

Tags: javascript, yui, firefox-9

Anyone else seeing odd JavaScript issues in Firefox 9?  We are having two issues.

The first case is that the instanceof operator is returning false when it should be returning true.  When I inspect using Firebug, the variable is definitely what I expect it to be, but it returns false. However, if I add additional breakpoints within my code, then it'll return true. I can do nothing different except for add more breakpoints and it will start working.

In another instance, we have created a variable scoped within a function which is then accessed globally. Something like this (note we are using YUI 2 to create a global namespace):

```
YAHOO.namespace("MyNS");

(function() {
  var _panel;

  YAHOO.MyNS.showPanel = function() {
    if (!_panel) {
      // code to create _panel
      _panel = new YAHOO.widget.Panel(...);
    }
    _panel.show();
  };

  YAHOO.MyNS.hidePanel = function() {
    if (_panel && _panel !== null && _panel.cfg.getProperty("visible")) {
      _panel.hide();
    }
  };
})();
```

On my individual page, YAHOO.MyNS.showPanel() is working fine, but then when I later call YAHOO.MyNS.hidePanel(), it fails because _panel is undefined.  If I place a breakpoint in firebug in both the showPanel() and hidePanel() methods, then _panel is not undefined.

We're stumped.  Because it's a new feature, I have tried turning off the type inference functionality in firefox to see if that made a difference and it didn't.

Comment: note: if (_panel && _panel !== null ...) is redundant...  null is falsy.  if (_panel && _panel.cfg && _panel.cfg.getProperty && ... would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've used YUI, let alone YUI2, but I don't know if this is a FireFox 9 specific issue, and if it is it's probably not a bug with FireFox 9.

It would be cleaner to create a `Panel` object with an internal reference to itself and a set of `show` and `hide` methods, and then attach that to the namespace - at least then you don't have to worry that the problem is the scoping of your closure.

Comment: Note: Not a YAHOO.widget.Panel, just an object called Panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can not blindly trust `console.log` because it may show you the object some time after you issue the call. Google Chrome suffers from this as well. You might only notice it in Firefox 9 because the JavaScript engine is faster.

This doesn't solve your bug though, but it might explain the weird behaviour.

I would suggest you make your check more explicit. Initialize `_panel` to `null` or `false` and check for that. If `new YAHOO.widget.Panel(...)` can return something other than a `Panel` object check for that as well.

At first glance your code looks fine, perhaps you remove the bug from the excerpt?

Comment: I can do those explicit checks, but I don't think that will help. new YAHOO.Widget.Panel will always return a Panel.  This code has remained unchanged since FF 3.5.  I just wanted to include the code because I didn't want the first comment to be "include a code sample please".